# error starting tigervnc-server code 98 - fedora27

Tags: fedora, vnc

after installing, creating user, editing etc, when I try to start service I get (after deleting .Xfiles from tmp, @SivaPrasath suggestion)

```
systemctl start vncserver@:1.service
Job for vncserver@:1.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl  status vncserver@:1.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
```

`systemctl` says:

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl  status vncserver@:1.service
● vncserver@:1.service - Remote desktop service (VNC)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@:1.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Tue 2018-05-15 19:26:13 -03; 1min 36s ago
  Process: 4284 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/runuser -l r_vnc -c /usr/bin/vncserver :1 -geometry 1280x1024 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4282 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/vncserver -kill :1 > /dev/null 2>&1 || : (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 15 19:26:10 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Remote desktop service (VNC)...
May 15 19:26:13 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: vncserver@:1.service: PID file /home/r_vnc/.vnc/localhost.localdomain:1.pid not readable (yet?) after start: Permission denied
May 15 19:26:13 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Remote desktop service (VNC).
May 15 19:26:13 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: vncserver@:1.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 15 19:26:13 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: vncserver@:1.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
```

`journalctl` says:

```
    - Unit UNIT has begun starting up.
May 15 16:42:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[13394]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 13453 (kill).
May 15 16:42:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1002.
-- Subject: Unit user@1002.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit user@1002.service has finished shutting down.
May 15 16:42:15 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=user@1002 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname
May 15 16:42:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of r_vnc.
-- Subject: Unit user-1002.slice has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit user-1002.slice has finished shutting down.
```

How can I fix the error?

Comment: A vncserver is already running on that address. Kill it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

If you kill your vncserver or unexpected dead, Please read /var/log/messages and you can find .X started files with errors like below.
At first, please verify Xvnc process not running.

```
Aug 13 12:11:11 www runuser: Warning: www.example.com:2 is taken because of /tmp/.X2-lock
...
Aug 13 12:12:52 www runuser: Warning: www.example.com:2 is taken because of /tmp/.X22-unix/X2
```

then you remove

```
# rm -f /tmp/.X2-lock
# rm -f /tmp/.X22-unix/X2
```

And set the VNC password for the user if it wasn't set. Once the password is set, you should be able to start the VNC server as expected.

```
# su - <user name>
$ vncpasswd
```

and restart your vncserver.

```
# systemctl restart vncserver@:2.sevice
```

Comment: Tks, @SivaPrasath. I am new to linux. There is no /var/log/messages file.

Comment: ps -e | grep Xvnc
 3109 ?        00:00:00 Xvnc

Comment: should I kill 3109?

Comment: check the hidden files in /tmp , and remove the file named with alphabet followed by numeric.

Comment: now it seems the problem is `vncserver@:1.service: PID file /home/r_vnc/.vnc/localhost.localdomain:1.pid not readable (yet?) after start: Permission denied`. Running systemctl as root

Comment: You might want to revisit the log rotation question, I added more to the answer. If you wish to post an Apache question ping me and I will contribute.